# GCP Vertex AI AutoML for images requires the image data to also reside in us-central1

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

We have our image data in us-west1, but since AutoML is available in us-central1, we are not able to use the image data in us-west1. We do not want to copy the data in us-central1. Is there any other option to use Vertex AI automl without moving the data to us-central1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation[1] that I went through, and since the feature of `AutoML for image data` is solely available in `us-central1 (Iowa)`, there is no other option aside from copying or moving the data in us-central1.

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/locations#feature-availability